# Can PROC FORMAT be used to sum within groups across many columns?

Tags: sas, bigdata

I have a dataset of ~900 million rows, each row representing a claim for a given patient in a 3 year period, and each claim having as many as 25 diagnosis codes arranged as variables, as well as a key that translates a certain subset of the codes into "chronic conditions."

Like so:

```
data claims;
   infile cards;
   input id $ type dg1 $ dg2 $ dg3 $ dg4 $ [...] dg25 $; 
   cards; 
A 40 A123 A234 B345 . [...] .
A 10 A234 . . . . [...] . 
B 40 C567 1234 Z4657 [...] . 
B 40 C567 1233 X4787 [...] . 
; 
run; 

data chrons;
infile cards; 
input chron nm $ code $ ;
cards; 
1 ckd A234
1 ckd C567
1 ckd 1233
2 copd B345
2 copd C233
3 diab A234
3 diab 1234
[...]
55 foo Z4657
55 foo X4787
;
run;
```

In order to decide whether the condition is "chronic" or not, I've got to count the number of claims for which a condition appeared (in any DG), with different minimum numbers of claims for different conditions.

At present I have done this using a very clunky data step that looks more or less like this:

```
/* first a SQL loop that puts the codes into macros: */

%macro chron(start,end); 

    proc sql noprint; 
        %do k=&start. %to &end.; 
            select strip(catt("'",code,"'")) 
                into :chron&k. separated by ',' 
            where chron=&k. 
           from chrons; 
        %end;
    quit; 
 %mend; 
 %chron(1,55); 


/* then a double loop array for each of the 55 conditions in any of the 25 vars */

data claims_1yr;
 set claims;
    array dgc(25) dg1-dg25;
    array cond(55) cond1-cond55; 
do i=1 to 55; 
    do j=1 to 25; 
if cond(i) < 1 then do; 
    if dgc(j) in (&&chron&i.) then cond&i.=1; else cond&i.=0;
end;
end; 
run;
```

Followed by some SQL sums by number of claims and further conditions based on claim type, etc. Some of the conditions have special circumstances, like having a list of codes that, if appearing in any dg{n} variable make the claim not count, or requirements that the code be within the first 2 dg{n} spaces.

What I'm wondering is if there's a simpler way to perhaps use PROC FORMAT (which I'm not particularly familiar with) and PROC MEANS or PROC SUMMARY to get a summary dataset in which each ID has a count of number of claims for each condition (regardless of which dg the code was in). The number of loops is brutal in terms of computation; the last time I ran it, it took almost 48 hours to complete.

A colleague suggested:

```
%macro sl(st,end); 
proc sql; 
%do l=&st. %to &end.; 
    create table claims_&l as
     select distinct id, 
     sum(case when (dg1 in (&&chron&l.) or 
    dg2 in (&&chron&l.) or 
    dg3 in (&&chron&l.) or 
    dg4 in (&&chron&l.) [...] or 
    dg25 in (&&chron&l.) then 1 else 0 end) as  chron&l. 
    from claims group by id; 
 %end;
quit;    
 %mend; 
%sl(1,55);
```

But this generally causes a segfault after about an hour.

The datastep isn't the worst thing in the world, but I wonder if this puzzle seems familiar to anyone or if there's an obvious answer that I'm overlooking (using anything other than SAS 9.3 is not an option, sadly).

The goal at the end is to have a dataset that looks like:

```
ID   Cond   Claims
A    diab    2
A    copd    1  
A    ckd     2
B    diab    1
B    ckd     2
B    foo     2
```

or

```
ID  cond1   cond2  cond3  [...] cond55
A   2        1       2    [...]   0
B   2        0       1    [...]   2
```

n.b. 
The average patient has ~70 claims in the file (there are ~13 million distinct patients). Previous runs have shown that about 40% of these have at least one chronic condition, and half of those (20% of total) have more than one chronic condition. Actually 'having' the condition is based on a minimum number of claims with the associated codes in a given time period (different minima for different conditions).

Thanks!

Comment: That's partial code, can you please post the actual code you tried, all are missing the FROM statement for example. And that's 900 Billion records * 25 per record that you're trying to summarize? You'll get a better solution on communities.sas.com since this is an efficiency type question, not a general is there a solution question.

Comment: And what are you using the Chron's data set for?

Comment: I am curious if there is a solution using PROC FORMAT--hence the question here. Guess I'll crosspost to SAS as well. The chron dataset is the crosswalk that is used to get the list of codes for each condition; I've clarified the SQL code that missed those lines when I was copying over.

Comment: Proc format can help, but I suspect a temporary array would work as well. Do you have answers for the rest of my questions?

Comment: Ah, I edited to clarify--it's 900 million, not billion rows--do you want me to post the code omitted by the ellipses? I fixed the from statements; they were missed when I was transcribing.

Comment: And is the data sorted or indexed on any fields, in particular ID?

Comment: No, the claims are organized chronologically and updated quarterly, a sort on ID only takes a couple of hours though, so it's not out of the question.

Comment: Ok, last question :), what do you want the output to look like based on what you have above? Are there any other fields you need to bring along, or would a count of the different categories of CHRON by ID be what you want? You really need to think through that well, to avoid having to run it multiple times.

Comment: Ideally, the ID / Cond1 / ... / Cond55 with the number of claims for each condition, or a long style ID / Condition / N with the number of claims for each condition. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post and example of the data you want based on the 2 inputs you show?

Comment: Do you only have 55 conditions?

Comment: Yeah, that's the number.

Comment: How do you get DIAB=3 claims for ID=A from the data about with only two claims?

Comment: Just being sloppy, I didn't do the actual counts when showing the desired result. The average ID has 70 claims in the actual dataset. I misread your comment and will update accordingly.

Comment: What is the cardinality on the distinct patient id's ?  Such as, 1B claims covering 20M patients ?  Do you have a rough estimate on number of chronic conditions per patient, and an estimate of the proportion of patients having no chronic indication ?  When a claim has no diagnoses of chronic nature should that be marked as a special case (i.e. cond56 means 'chronically healthy' w.r.t this claim and would mean none of the criteria for cond1 to cond55 were met)

Comment: @Richard I see that you answered based on reasonable assumptions below--I'm updating the question to include these parameters. I don't need to mark the "healthy" patients for this particular project, but it's a useful thought for future comparison purposes (in fact I'm only concerned with patients who have _more than one_ chronic condition because it triggers a related eligibility).  Thanks a lot for the thoughtful engagement here.

Answer (score 2):

This uses 'value' in **array** and creates CONDn variables and count by ID.

```
data claims;
   infile cards missover;
   input id $ type (dg1-dg5)($); 
   cards; 
A 40 A123 A234 B345
A 10 A234
B 40 C567 1234 Z4657
B 40 C567 1233 X4787
;;;; 
   run; 

data chrons;
   infile cards; 
   input chron nm $ code $;
   cards; 
1 ckd A234
1 ckd C567
1 ckd 1233
2 copd B345
2 copd C233
3 diab A234
3 diab 1234
;;;;
   run; 
filename FT77F001 temp;
data _null_;
   file FT77F001;
   set chrons;
   by chron nm;
   if first.chron then put +3 'Cond' chron '=' @;
   put code :$quote. 'in DG' @;
   if not last.chron then put ' or ' @;
   if last.chron then do;
      put ';' +3 'label Cond' chron '=' nm:$quote. ';';
      end;
   run;

data want1(keep=id cond:) / view=want1;
   set claims;
   array DG[*] dg:;
   %inc FT77F001 / source2;
   run;
proc summary data=want1 nway;
   class id;
   output out=want2(drop=_type_) sum(cond:)=;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

[image: From SAS Log]

Comment: The text data is written to the temp file, I think that goes in the work library, which will disappear when the session ends.

Comment: @Reeza Yes the "wall paper" file is temporary.  Do you think it should be permanent?

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could reference all elements of an array that way, very cool. Assuming that SAS just does a 'do over' loop within each 'DG'-- Is that functionally different than the double-loop that is in my data step now?

Comment: @BenLerner I don't know how it works under the hood.  In another question the other day I used the same technique and another SO user mentioned that "in array" is pretty quick, I think he did some performance testing.  I expect it is faster that what you were doing but the only way to know is to test both.

Comment: Thanks! I'll run a test on my toy dataset (1M rows) tomorrow and see; I imagine you're right and however the implementation of "in array" is coded is probably faster than doing it explicitly.

Comment: The colon operator is a short cut and references all variables that start with the prefix. There are several other ways to list variables DG1-DG25, DG1--DG25 that have slightly different interpretations. https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/05/29/6-easy-ways-to-specify-a-list-of-variables-in-sas.html

Comment: @data_null_, nope, it's fine, just noting something for the OP - since she mentioned an issue with space.

Comment: The colon operator  to control the pointer when assigning a format in the file statement is a new one for me--led me to this great SUGI paper  <www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p073-26.pdf> on the various usages of colons in SAS (most of which are not clearly documented elsewhere, of course). I was aware of the `varname:` list usage, but not that you could reference all members of an array with simply `in [arrayname]`

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd approach this would be to use a datastep to transpose the dataset to one row per diagnosis code, applying your Chronic Condition format to that column.  Then `PROC TABULATE` is probably your best bet to get a count of diagnoses per condition per ID.  That initial transpose won't be fast, but it'll use the data step so it will work even though it's a big file, and should not take hours unless your disk is way too slow.  Just make sure your output dataset is filtered to just the three or so variables you need - ID, diag. code, type I think?

You can use the CNTLIN feature on PROC FORMAT to import your chronic conditions.  You need at minimum:

- START = input to format (i.e., diag codes)
- LABEL = output from format (i.e., chronic conditions)
- FMTNAME = whatever you want to name it, with a $ for character
- TYPE = 'c' (character)
- A single row with HLO='o' and an empty label or whatever non-matches should be collapsed into ('others' that don't match the format)

Then `proc format cntlin=[formatdataset]; run;` will import it.

Comment: Thanks--I have already been able to cntlin the chrons dataset, but the transpose results in a ~20 billion row table, and space is not too easy to come by in the environment I have to do this in (need to do this to 4 of these datasets, all 60-90gb). The space limitation is one of the reasons I hoped to do it in a more elegant way (which it seems that formats and a 2d array maybe could do with proc means or proc tabulate, but having trouble wrapping my head around whether I'm pipedreaming or if there is a "there" there).

Comment: Can you create it as a view?  That should pipe the information into PROC TABULATE row by row.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an in-memory requirement for the desired diagnostic frequency table as a hash table.

900M claims with average of 70 claims per patient means there are ~13M distinct patients

Suppose an horrific average of 10 chronic conditions per patients.  So you would have 130M rows in the vertical data layout form of your goal (ID,Condition,Freq).

Further suppose an in-memory hash object key+data requiring 75 bytes per row. So a hash that contains the complete desired vertical form result might need >= ~9G RAM.

So you could in a single pass of the data, perform diagnoses -> conditions mapping **and** compute frequencies.

Mapping via `IN` based evaluations as code-generated from the chronic condition control table (per @ data *null*) is likely one of the fastest solutions.  The generated code could possibly be further optimized -- My understanding is that the **OR** evaluation in SAS data step code is a full path evaluation, meaning every clause is done. For example

```
<condition-1> = (clause-1) OR (clause-2) … OR … (clause-k);
<condition-2> = (clause-1) OR (clause-m) … OR … (clause-n);
```

Also, clause-1 is a mapper (or categorization criteria) used by more than one condition.  Your actual control data may have distinct mapping, meaning a single diagnosis code always maps to only one condition.

Regardless, a code-generator could produce a single test mapping `select` statement

```
select 
  when (clause-1) do; condition1=1; end;
  when (clause-2) do; condition2=1; condition14=1; end; /* a non-distinct mapping in the control data */
  …
  when (clause-k) do; condition<p> = 1; end;
  otherwise condition_healthy = 1;
end;
```

From `data _null_`'s answer, the (clause-k) would be `("<some-code>" in DG)`

Comment: These are excellent points--the environment involved here tops out at 8G RAM (but a patient having more than 4 chronic conditions is rare). The point re: OR evaluation is also well-taken, since I'm going to have to fiddle with data/_null/_'s general case for the exclusions and special cases this is a super helpful comment/answer. Thanks tons!